# Parsing json lines using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a large json file with millions of lines. This file also has some error messages in it. Below is the sample:

```
{"MEASUREMENT_1":"12345678","MEASUREMENT_2":"123456789012","MEASUREMENT_3":"MEASUREMENT_TYPE","MEASUREMENT_4":1111111111111,"MEASUREMENT_5":-1122,"MEASUREMENT_6":-2233,"MEASUREMENT_7":"123456789"}
{"MEASUREMENT_1":"87654321","MEASUREMENT_2":"987654321098","MEASUREMENT_3":"MEASUREMENT_TYPE_2","MEASUREMENT_4":222222222222,"MEASUREMENT_5":-4455,"MEASUREMENT_6":-6677,"MEASUREMENT_7":"123456789"}
[2015-12-02 02:00:02,530] WARN Reconnect due to socket error: null 
[2015-12-02 02:00:02,633] WARN Reconnect due to socket error: null
```

As expected, the below code throws a `ValueError` because of the error message line in the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import pandas as pd # Version 0.21.0
df = pd.read_json(file, lines=True)
```

As this is very large file, I have used `chunksize` and an expection, as below:

```
max_records = 1e5
df = pd.read_json(file, lines=True, chunksize=max_records)
filtered_data = pd.DataFrame() # Initialize the dataframe
try:
   for df_chunk in df:
       filtered_data = pd.concat([filtered_data, df_chunk])
except ValueError:
       print ('\nSome messages in the file cannot be parsed')
```

But the drawback of the above approach is it misses some of the lines. Is there any better way to do this? I went through the documentation of http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html but couldn't find anything that can ignore the unparsed lines. Can someone help?

Comment: Is it viable to get rid of these lines?

Comment: Looks like each "measurement" is its own json object, so perhaps your file has lots of json objects and not just one, and therefore fails?

Comment: Why do you have the for loop inside the try block, rather than a try block inside each iteration of the for loop?

Comment: @coldspeed It is not neccesary to remove these error lines, but If I can load it do a dataframe, that should do for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found a solution to get rid of error messages in the file. However this procedure adds additional time to clean the file and saves it as new file

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3.5

    import re
    import pandas as pd # Version 0.21.0

    def clean_data(filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as inputfile:
            for row in inputfile:
                if re.match("\[", row) is None:
                    yield row

   with open(clean_file,  'w') as outputfile:
        for row in clean_data(filename):
            outputfile.write(row)

   max_records = 1e5
   df = pd.read_json(clean_file, lines=True, chunksize=max_records)
```